# Windows8, website "blocked" .. or something, very weird issue

Tags: windows-8, firewall, website

Run into a very weird issue on my Windows8 laptop tonight, which honestly left me baffled.

When I try to open battleping.com in the browser, either Chrome or Firefox, they don't load, and timeout with Server Not Found/dns resolution timeout. Installed Opera, same thing. Try in IE.. it works. Battleping app itself unable to contact their login server as well.

If I do a ping it resolves the IP properly. Adding ip/host in hosts file has the same results. Set DNS to Google's, same thing. Made a small app myself, that loads battleping,com and shows me a status code and response text: 200 OK and the site's main page html code returned just fine. Firewall/win defender turned off, same results.

The f. could be going on? oO

Note, might be related: got the laptop at work, where we connect to an open Wifi, after which you must open any page in the browser and it loads a custom site instead where you put a user/password and then you have normal access. I think I may have done that by trying to open battleping.com first, and might be related, although it doesn't explain why ping/IE/custom app does work.

Comment: Could battleping.com be on a blocklist for your company internet? Can you access the site on another computer in your office? Why is it blocking battleping.com in this way? IP's can change easily - hostnames can't.

Comment: I can access it on phone, and also on the laptop with IE/ping/custom app, so it can't be blocked.

Comment: Possibly that individual machine has been prevented from accessing? can you access the site by "ht.tp://battleping-ip-address/" ?

Comment: With the IP it works.

Comment: Now it's working again.. I'm completely baffled as to what could have caused this, it makes no sense at all how it worked with some apps but not with others, maybe some w8 security stuff?

Comment: Glad it now works for you but rather frustrating that we are still nowhere towards finding out what caused it. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you had extensions, add-ons, cached pages or browser redirect PUPs that were blocking access in a particular browser.

Comment: the battleping app itself couldn't access their server either, not just the browsers.